# What is the most efficient way to find union of two collections?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

```
public IEnumerable<SummaryItem> GetSummaryData(SummarySettings settings)
{
   return GetSummaryReportData(startTime, endTime, settings.AgentIds);
}
```

After I wrote my code I realized that I need to add  some `ids` to the `settings.AgentIds`.

So I do the following

```
public IEnumerable<SummaryItem> GetSummaryData(SummarySettings settings)
{
    if (settings.LabelIds != null && settings.LabelIds.Any())
    {
       var labelGroups = _agentsGroupsStorage.Values.Where(x => settings.LabelIds.Contains(x.Id));
       var labelAgentIds = labelGroups.SelectMany(x => x.AgentIds); // IEnumerable<Guid>

       settings.AgentIds = new GuidCollection(labelAgentIds.Union(settings.AgentIds).ToList());
    }

   return GetSummaryReportData(startTime, endTime, settings.AgentIds);
}
```

How can I improve my algorithm to combine two collection?

Maybe without creating `new GuidCollection` ? Or I need to use `Aggregate` but not `Union`?

Comment: 1) What is wrong with this implementation? What makes you worrying? 2) Aggregate aggregates, it reduces a collection to single value 3) Union is blazingly fast because it is lazy, just constructs kind of linked list.

Comment: Yes. I don't really understand what you're asking for. Is there a problem with your current implementation? Is it too slow? If clarity is the goal, I think you're there already.

Comment: @Andrey Im worrying about speed and memoty

Comment: @Anatoly what exactly makes you worry about speed and memory? You have giant lists? Or your code runs slow?  You are solving problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Andrey How can I chage (in-place) my `setting.AgentIds`? I mean just add `labelAgentIds` without creating a  `new GuidCollection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the approximate implementation of a Union:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Union(this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
{
    var hs=new Hashset<T>(left);
    for(var item in right)
    {
        hs.Add(item);
    }
    return hs;
}
```

As you can see, it makes use of a set-based collection to make the union. This leverages the speed of hash tables to make the operation very efficient indeed. It might be possible to make a more optimal solution with fore-knowlege of the data that you are trying to collect, but in the general case, this is as quick as it gets.

Comment: How can I chage (in-place) my setting.AgentIds? I mean just add labelAgentIds without creating a new GuidCollection

Comment: That would very much depend on the implementation of the GuidCollection. What's a GuidCollection? Is this really worth doing? Have you isolated this code as a performance hotspot? If not, I suggest you move on and spend your time on more important matters.

Comment: Its a `Collection<Guid>`

Comment: In which case, it delegates to `List<Guid>`, so no, there's no efficient way to do this directly on a `GuidCollection` because you'll need to do a O(n) search on every insertion to check for duplicates.

Comment: My `labelAgentIds` may contains a duplicates after `SelectMany`. How can I use `Aggregate` to avoid them?

Comment: You don't need to. Just let the Union implementation weed them out for you. Pre-filtering here is a waste of time. Union is the best choice for this problem.

Comment: Why? Is to expansive for memory? It also use HashSet?

Comment: Your collection of `labelAgentIds` is a temporary variable. It doesn't need to have duplicates removed in order for the Union to work, so expending extra work to dedupe this collection is a waste of time because you'll still need to run a union with your existing data on the following line. You don't need a deduped copy of just  `labelAgentIds`, because it's not used anywhere else. Running the union will do everything you need. You seem intent on creating more work out of a solved problem.