# How to Union two collections efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I have the following algorithms to find union of two collections.

```
IEnumerable<IGroup> labelGroups = _agents.Where(x => settings.LabelIds.Contains(x.Id));
IEnumerable<Guid>labelAgentIds = labelGroups.SelectMany(x => x.AgentIds);

settings.AgentIds = new Collection<Guid>(labelAgentIds.Union(settings.AgentIds).ToList());
```

Or

```
IEnumerable<IGroup> labelGroups = _agents.Where(x => settings.LabelIds.Contains(x.Id));
agentIds = labelGroups.Aggregate(agentIds, (current, label) => current.Union(label.AgentIds));
```

Which one should I use? Help me to compare this algorithms (speed and memory).

Comment: I think that use must to use second algorithm

Comment: Just check it with `Stopwatch` class or using performance analysis

Comment: Do you want avoid duplicate items? If yes, you can use `HashSet<T>` and method `UnionWith`. As @Fabjan said, a `Stopwatch` could be nice to check the performance.

Comment: @FelipeOriani yes, I want

Comment: Maybe can help you http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779641/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-union-of-two-collections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For best performance start by putting the `settings.LabelIds` into a `HashSet`

```
var labelIds = new HashSet<int>(settings.LabelIds);
```

Then use the hashset for fast lookup O(1)

```
var labelAgentIds = _agents.Where(x => labelIds.Contains(x.Id)).SelectMany(x => x.AgentIds);
```

If you know the `labelAgentIds` and `settings.AgentIds` never have the same Id's you can use `Concat` otherwise use `Union` to ensure no duplicates.

```
settings.AgentIds = new Collection<Guid>(labelAgentIds.Union(settings.AgentIds).ToList())
```

Using your `Aggregate` way would be slower.

Comment: Can you please explain why it would be slower?

Comment: If you run Aggregate you have to execute union for every item in the list. For example if you want to concatenate two string you wouldn't loop the 2nd one and append the characters one by one. But more importantly using union plainly more easily show the intention of the code. And makes it easier for future maintainers.